# How do I use material icons in my Android Studio project, using the material dependency?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

I don't know how I use the material icons provided by Google can be used in my project. For example, lets say I want a reference to the chat icon:

https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Symbols+Outlined:chat:FILL@0;wght@400;GRAD@0;opsz@48&icon.query=message&icon.platform=android

I have this dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0"
```

I tried this, but the icon does not exists:

```
com.google.android.material.R.drawable.chat
```

I prefer not to download all images and adding them manually, I was hoping the library was an equivalent of `SFSymbols` on iOS.

Comment: Its jetpack compose project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you use (`com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0`) do not contains icons in it. You can see for yourself by downloading them [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.google.android.material#com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0).

Unless you want an enormous application, you should really not add all material icons to your app. A better solution is to select which icons to add and reuse.

Android studio have a build-in tool called [vector-asset-studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#running) to add material icons more easely on the fly.